# How can I de-duplicate all rows in a Google Doc across a certain column?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-docs

So let's say I've got a document with ten thousand rows. Most of these rows are near-duplicates of other rows, and for right now I only want the first row in which any given column-I value appears.

If the contents of each column I exist in a thousand rows each, at the end of this I'd end up with ten rows.

I know I can use the UNIQUE command to get a list of the unique values, but that's only about a quarter of the way to what I want (which is the rows themselves who have those unique values).

What's the best way to / how can I get what I want, which is only the first row in the spreadsheet for each unique value of the column in question?

Comment: What _is_ the question exactly?

Comment: How can I do this thing that I want to do? Sorry, will clarify in the question body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This assumes that the data you are processing is in columns A to K, and you are looking at column I for unique values:

`=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(UNIQUE(I:I),{I:I,A:H,J:K},{2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,10,11},0)))`

Comment: Excellent! I was able to use this script to get what I needed. I wound up adding a Sheet!Data modifier to the formula so that I could do it on a new sheet, and it's exactly what I needed. Thank you.